# I can't display data in a table with vue

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to display data in a table via vuejs but it throws the following error.
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null"

```
export default {
    created: function() {
        this.getCiudades();
    },
    data() {
      return {
        ciudades: [],
      }
    },
    methods: {
        getCiudades: function() {
            var urlciudades = 'ciudadesjson';
            axios.get(urlciudades).then(response => {
                this.ciudades = response.data;
                });
            }
    }
}
```

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="ciudad in ciudades" v-bind:key="ciudad.id">
    <td>
      @{{ ciudad.id }}
    </td>
    <td>
      @{{ ciudad.nombres }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: It seems at least one of the items is `null`. change `ciudad.id` to `ciudad` and comment `ciudad.nombres` to see if there is such an item.

Comment: Look in your browser's _Network_ console to inspect the response coming back from your server.

Comment: Can you please check the network and add the `axios` response here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(ciudad,i) in ciudades" :key="i">
                    <td>
                        @{{ ciudad.id }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @{{ ciudad.nombres }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

If ciudad.id is blank in any of the object in the array, then you can use the index number as a key, or ciucad.id.

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that your are getting response from your `method/function` by console.log-ing you data like below:

```
methods: {
  getCiudades() {
    var urlciudades = 'ciudadesjson';
    axios.get(urlciudades).then(response => {
      this.ciudades = response.data;
      console.log('myData:', response.data)
    });
  }
}
```

then the simple solution is to add `v-if` to `table`

```
<table v-if='ciudades.length'>...</table>
```

or initiate your data with placeholder key and value

```
data() {
  return {
    ciudades: [
      {
        id: 0,
        nombres: '',
      },
    ],
  };
},
```